# TypeError: Tutorial is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im learning node js and MongoDB through a tutorial. Im creating a CRUD.
The connection with MongoDB is successful, but it shows this error: TypeError: Tutorial is not a constructor.

models/tutorial.model.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Tutorial = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  published: Boolean
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("tutorial", Tutorial)
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./config/db")
var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
}

//connnect the database
if(connectDB()){
    console.log("connected")
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to application" })
})

//setting the port 
require("./routes/tutorial.routes")(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

controller/tutorial.controller.js

```
const db = require("../models")
const Tutorial = db.tutorials

//create and save
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    //validate request
    if(!req.body.title) {
        res.status(400).send({message: "Content cannot be empty"})
    }

    const tutorial = new Tutorial({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        published: req.body.published ? req.body.published : false
    })

    tutorial
        .save(tutorial)
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occured while creating the Tutorial"
            })
        })
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you show the contents of `models/index.js` file please?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech its empty

Comment: So what are you importing in the first line `const db = require("../models")` in controller/tutorial.controller.js file?

Answer (score 1):

When you require a directory, node looks for the `index.js` file inside the directory.

This line:

```
const db = require("../models")
```

is loading your empty `models/index.js` file (could also be `models.js` but I would advise sticking with the `index.js` file as that's the standard)

This file should load all models and export them as an object:

```
module.exports = {
  tutorial: require("./tutorial")
}
```

Which will allow you to use:

```
const db = require("../models")
const Tutorial = db.tutorial
```

note I dropped the s after `db.tutorial` to stay consistent and avoid typos.